# Installing Z3 on Mac Os Mountain Lion

Tags: z3

I can't seem to install Z3 (4.3.1) on Max OS X Mountain Lion (with Xcode / Command Line tool installed properly).  The problem is autconf is not installed/shipped with Xcode and its command line tool.

Do I need to download and install autoconf/automake etc from source ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, we need autoconf to install Z3 v4.3.1. 
The next release will not have this dependency.
In the meantime, we can build the `unstable` (work-in-progress) branch without using autoconf.
[Here](http://z3.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Building%20the%20unstable%20%28working-in-progress%29%20branch&referringTitle=Documentation) are the instruction to compile the `unstable` branch.
The same instructions can be used also to compile the `contrib` branch. This branch is essentially `contrib` + external (non-MS) contributtions.